# Fonts not loading in Desktop version of Safari/Firefox

Tags: fonts

I am using Wordpress to construct my site, this issue is very new and no plugins seem to be causing it.

The fonts do not load properly ONLY in the desktop version of Safari and Firefox

The preferred view can be seen below in Chrome and mobile devices:
[image: chrome]

The unpreferred view can be seen below in the Desktop version of Safari and Firefox:
[image: safari/firefox]

See for yourself:
[www.TattiniBoots.com](https://www.TattiniBoots.com)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you be more specific? At first glance the only bit that looks wrong to me (Windows Chrome and Firefox, comparing to iPhone Safari) "WELCOME TO TATTINI BOOTS Premium Italian English Riding Dressage Boots" and that doesn't look like in a font you're loading.

Comment: However there are different ways of embedding fonts using different file formats, so if it does vary between browsers it might be because the browsers want fonts in different formats. So it might be worth checking exactly what the problem browsers are trying to load, and that the font embedding CSS is set up correctly for that format by whatever mechanism you're using (plugin? theme?)

Comment: Images have been added to demonstrate what is preferred/unpreferred

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're only specifying `font-family: Marcellus;` inside a `@media (max-width: 600px) {}`, and your desktop browsers are wider than that. Everything else is using the default stack of "Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial".

Comment: I'm not sure why this is working for you in Chrome, though. It doesn't for me. And this isn't particularly a WordPress issue: even if the autoptimize plugin was breaking this for you somehow (and you say it's not a plugin) you'd do better asking them for help with that.

Comment: Can you verify if it working for you in chrome now? The concern is that this is a VERY new issue and never took place as of about a week ago. Only 3 new plugins were installed and de-activating those have NO effect

Comment: No, looks the same to me: Helvetica normally and Marcellus only if I tell the browser to pretend to be a mobile device. I don't know if this would be a plugin or not: I'd guess this was set up by hand in the theme or child theme stylesheet?

Comment: Its confusing because this issue has never occurred before

Comment: Can you let me know if it working for you now?

Comment: Yes, that looks better now for me

Comment: Great. It was a plugin issue with "Product Suggestions for WooCommerce"

Answer (score 0):

This was simply a plugin issue with Product Suggestions for WooCommerce: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cart-products-suggestions-for-woocommerce/

In the instance that a new issue occurs that was not taking place prior to installation, it can almost always be attributed to a plugin issue